# Jquery Mobile. Redirect from main site makes site small

Tags: jquery, redirect, mobile

I hope you can help.
I'm setting up a basic redirect using the code below.

```
    $iphone = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone");
$android = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Android");
$palmpre = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"webOS");
$berry = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"BlackBerry");
$ipod = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPod");

if ($iphone || $android || $palmpre || $ipod || $berry == true){
    header('location: http://www.ignitiondrivingschool.mobi');
    exit();
}
```

I've done this on other sites with no problem, however, when I redirect from dev.ignitiondrivinglessons.co.uk the styling goes small. Refresh the page in the phone and it resumes as normal.

[image: Small Version straight from redirect]
Small Version straight from redirect

[image: Normal view once you refresh the page]
Normal view once you refresh the page

Any help would be wonderful.

Thanks
Mark